# Воспроизведение видео андроид

Tags: java, android, видео

В своем приложении необходимо воспроизводить `iptv` видео.Есть ссылки `http`, `upd`, `rtmp`. Сначала начал делать через `surfaceview` и `MediaPlayer`. Но кроме `http` ничего не воспроизводит. Даже такую ссылку

> http://37.235.164.87:81/udp/225.50.66.21:1234

отказался воспроизводить. Причем встроенный андроид плеер то же. Подумал делать через библиотеку `vitamio`. Но узнал что для ее работы на устройстве еще нужно и устанавливать какую то их программу и передумал. `Vlc` компонент как установить не понял. Подскажите, кто знает, какую-нибудь библиотеку для воспроизведения видео, чтобы поддерживала минимум выше описанные форматы. Чтобы библиотека не была тормозной. И может у кого в закладках завалялась инструкция по сборки библиотеки под `Android Strudio`.

Answer (score 4):

Vitamio должно работать нормалаьно, vlc нужно компилить из исходников или воспользоваться https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk, тут so'шки и обертка, [пример](https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample/src), может уже устарел.

Comment: Как раз тут и сижу.Подглядел, что AC3 player использует эти библиотеки и в нем мои форматы идут.mrmaffen - это собранная vcl?Что будет лучше fmpeg или mrmaffen?Просто только что нашел и потерял уже что Vitamio работает если на телефоне установить еще и их приложение, если его нет то не работает.Видать кодеки какие то.

Comment: По ссылке - собранная либа, ffmpeg - это набор библиотек, как раз используемый vlc и наверняка vitamio. По поводу "установить еще и их приложение" я запускал семпл vitamio у меня работало, правда давно.

Comment: Т.е. можно по ссылке установить и все.Все рано все библиотеки используют vcl

Comment: В AC3 player лежит в папке lib.Ложу в свою папку libs wrapper и ничего